# .Net5 code migration gets nullable value assignment warning

Tags: c#, migration, resharper, .net-5

I have .net48 project which i convert to .Net5.
The project currently have 2 targets, net48 and net5.

when I running resharper static analysis test, I get a warning

> Possible 'null' assignment to non-nullable entity

for the line:

```
var memberInfoArr = typeof(TEnum).GetMember(enumValue.ToString());
```

the GetMember() method is not nullable in net48, and in Net5 it is nullable (GetMember?()) according to MSDN docs.

possible solution is to wrap line with
`#if NETFRAMEWORK` and `#elif NET`.

I prefer not to use compilation flags or nullforgive char.

is there a better solution for this case? (disable with a comment?)

Comment: The warning is telling you that `GetMember` _could_ return null. What do you want to do when that happens? Throw an exception? Ignore it with a `!` operator? Return an empty array instead? Return null?

Comment: I want check for null and throw exception if there is an error, but still support net48 and net5 and of course take care of the warning in the best practice

Comment: Okay, so check for null and throw an exception. What's the problem? The code should've been doing that in the first place, but now the compiler can tell you that you forgot to do it. Or, as gunr2171 mentioned, use the `!` operator to say "I know this won't be null because I've taken care of that in my own way." There's no need to use `#if` because the code doesn't need to be different for each target. It just needs to be better for net48 than it was.

Comment: Is you want to disable the warning for Resharper then a line `// ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute` above the line with a warning should do the trick

Comment: @madreflection - thank for clarifying the diff regarding to the compiler.
It is not complely correct since the return value is different in net48 and net5, therefor I cant use the '!' operator in net48, and the null check looks ruderant in net48.
I changed the code with adding null check to support both frameworks and disable with a comments as AndrewSilver suggested.
Thank you all!